# What are some numbers that are can be factored by Hurwitz primes but not Gaussian primes?

Tags: quaternions

Since gaussian primes can factor conventional prime numbers like 5, I was wondering about the same question but for quaternions.

Comment: $3=(1+i+j)(1-i-j)$. We have $(i+j)^2=-2$ so this is quite like factoring $3$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $11$ will do the job. It's not a sum of two squares, so it can't be a product of Gaussian primes, but it can be written
$$
11 = ( 1 + 3i + j)(1 - 3i - j).
$$

Comment: (If you want to learn more about this question and how to approach it systematically, you will want some tools from Algebraic Number Theory.)

Comment: Or more generally, any prime which is 3 mod 4.